# Type error with classmethod constructors

Tags: python, constructor, class-method

I'm implementing several constructors using `@classobj`. I'm not only setting variables, but also calling methods in the new class:

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def constructor1(cls,x,y):
        self=cls
        self.__x = x
        self.__somemethod(self,y)

    ...
```

I get the following error:

```
unbound method __somemethod() must be called with Example instance as 
first argument (got classobj instance instead)
```

How do I resolve this problem?

Comment: What's the reasoning behind using `cls` instead of `self` and then doing `self = cls`?

Comment: What is your use case -- are you attemping to use `@classmethod`'s as factory functions?

Comment: Looks like `self = cls` is a mistaken attempt to create an instance: `self = cls(...)`. Hence yes this classmethod is a factory function.

Comment: This is doing it the wrong way. In this particular case you don't actually need a factory function, just an init method which can take multiple optional args, with defaults: `__init__(self, x=None, y=None)`. Writing code that reaches inside the object like `self.__x = x` and `self.__somemethod(self,y)` is a code smell that you're doing it wrong - just make `__init__` take multiple optional args and be smarter about defaults for the args that aren't passed. (`self.__somemethod(self,y)` is presumably a setter method, right? You mightn't need it if `__init__` allowed you initialize y directly)

Comment: If `self.__somemethod(self,y)` does something fancier like computing y based on the value of x (or other things), we can and should still move that the call to `__somemethod` into `__init__` (and any other methods that need to call it). Classmethods should never be reaching inside an object like this, except as an absolute kludge last resort, e.g. when you need to monkey-patch someone else's existing API to overcome shortcomings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're wanting your class method to be a constructor, you probably want to be creating an instance of the class you get passed in as `cls`. I suspect you're trying to do that with your `self = cls` line, but you're not actually creating a new instance because you've neglected to put parentheses. There are some other issues too, but I think that is the key one. Here's a fixed constructor:

```
@classmethod
def constructor1(cls,x,y):
    self=cls()                # parentheses added, to make it a call
    self.__x = x
    self.__somemethod(y)      # self is not needed as a parameter here
    return self               # return the new instance
```

Comment: That's _exactly_ what I just found (see my own answer below), thanks!

Comment: And I also forgot the `return self` in my example. Excellent answer. +1

Answer (score 2):

looks like `__somemethod` is not a classmethod, but a "normal" method.
And normal methods expect an actual instance as the first parameter, not a class.
And because `constructor1` is decorated as a `@classmethod`, `cls` is the class itself - which you pass to `__somemethod`.
That cannot work.

You should reconsider your design approach.

Addendum:

Maybe you meant  something like this?

```
@classmethod
def constructor1(cls, x, y):
    newinst = cls()
    newinst.__x = x
    cls.__somemethod(newinst, y)
```

That'd be better written as followed, though:

```
@classmethod
def constructor1(cls, x, y):
    newinst = cls()
    newinst.__x = x
    newinst.__somemethod(y)
```

actually, I like neighter approach  - seems like a codesmell of overcomplexity to me.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a template of what I think you're trying to achieve...

```
import random

class Something(object):
    def __init__(self, value, **kwargs):
        self.value = value
        for k, v in kwargs.iteritems():
            setattr(self, k, v)
    @classmethod
    def from_iterable(cls, iterable):
        return cls(sum(iterable), description='came from from_iterable')
    @classmethod
    def make_random(cls):
        return cls(random.randint(1,1000), is_random=True)

a = Something.from_iterable([1, 2, 3])
b = Something.make_random()
c = Something(56)

for obj in (a, b, c):
    print type(obj), obj.value

<class '__main__.Something'> 6
<class '__main__.Something'> 308
<class '__main__.Something'> 56
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to ch3ka's answer and Tim Pietzcker's comment, I found my error: I used the factory method from http://jjinux.blogspot.co.at/2008/11/python-class-methods-make-good.html and forgot the `()` in the line `self=cls()`. Now it works just fine:

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def constructor1(cls,x,y):
        self=cls()
        self.__x = x
        self.__somemethod(self,y)

    ...
```